# How to specify external properties files in application.properties in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, path

I have a project `Projects/MyApp`.

I have external properties files `Projects/files`.

I try to use in `application.properties`:

```
spring.config.location=classpath:../files
```

`files` directory contains `application-database.properties`

I've tried also `spring.config.location=file:../files/application-database.properties`

but It doesn't work. What is wrong?

Comment: As far as I understand the question, you have a problem while picking the file from classpath. You don't need to mention src/main/resources as it is default classpath. Also use relative path not absolute path.

Comment: where should place the files? In the same directory as project.war? Is something like this suitable -> spring.config.additional-localtion:file../../../database.properties ?

Comment: You dont need to worry about after build directory structure in case of you are packaging it inside your war. Just mention the relative file name placed in classpath. In case you want to externalise set some base directory and read it from application.properties and then place your all file inside that base directory. eg basedirectory = /opt/base.

Comment: Dir/MyApp and Dir/MyAppFiles. I try to use in application.properties spring.config.location=classpath:../MyAppFiles/application-database.properties, it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I understand you what to use properties for your database in the `application-database.properties` file and you don't want to get credentials at your `war` file after the build. You can put your database credentials to Idea Environment Variables and remove from the `.properties` file. What do you think about it?
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to specify with it but using external file?

Comment: @Donatello I sure you can find it here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I will try to find a way but in any case your method works